# continuous writing to a text file and ensuring that a new file is create each time

Tags: python

I'm writing to a text file using the code below. the setup is:

1. read '\n'-terminated data off of the serial port.
2. create a text file containing only one line of text.

_

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial ( 2 , baudrate = 57600 , timeout = 1 )
AngleText = open ("data.txt" , "w")

while True:

    line = ser.readline().strip('^\n\r')
    print line
    AngleText.write (str(line))
    AngleText.flush()

ser.close()
```

The problem is, data gets appended to the text file. what I want is to have a text file containing only one line.  How should I solve this? thanks!

Comment: You do realise that once you've overwritten the file it's gone, right? So you're just throwing away each line when the next one comes in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One solution is to move the `open` and `close` statements inside the loop so that each time you get data you overwrite the file. For example:

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial ( 2 , baudrate = 57600 , timeout = 1 )
while True:

    line = ser.readline().strip('^\n\r')
    print line
    AngleText = open ("data.txt" , "w")
    AngleText.write (str(line))
    AngleText.close()

ser.close()
```